# why my program running continously and not stoping?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an template which is my class assignment.
I used a switch statement in the do while loop while the condition is if enter variable not equal to 16 you should terminate the program

I'vve already used break statment in every case but it isn't working

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int op;

    cout << "Please enter choice between 1 to 15 For Different Operations "
         << endl;

    cout << "1. Create List(create a new list(presumably empty))" << endl;
    cout << "2. Insertion" << endl;
    cout << "3. Deletion" << endl;
    cout << "4. Update(replace the element)" << endl;
    cout << "5. Start" << endl;
    cout << "6. Next" << endl;
    cout << "7. Back" << endl;
    cout << "8. Tail" << endl;
    cout << "9. Find" << endl;
    cout << "10. Copy" << endl;
    cout << "11. Get(display current index and element)" << endl;
    cout << "12. Size / length" << endl;
    cout << "13. Display list" << endl;
    cout << "14. De - allocate list" << endl;
    cout << "15. Exit" << endl;

    cin >> op;
    do {
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Creating the List" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "inserting... " << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Deleting... " << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "updating... " << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "starting... " << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "next... " << endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "back... " << endl;
            break;
        case 8:
            cout << "Tail... " << endl;
            break;
        case 9:
            cout << "Find... " << endl;
            break;
        case 10:
            cout << "Copying... " << endl;
            break;
        case 11:
            cout << "Getting... " << endl;
            break;
        case 12:
            cout << "Size... " << endl;
            break;
        case 13:
            cout << "Display... " << endl;
            break;
        case 14:
            cout << "Deallocate... " << endl;
            break;
        case 15:
            terminate;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter the correct choice " << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (op != 16);
    return 0;
}
```

i expect the the cout output in every choice user made and then stop for taking input

Comment: The case `15` has a statement `terminate`.   That doesn't do anything.   You probably intend it to be `terminate()`.   For the `default` cases, the `break` exits the `switch`, not the loop.

Comment: how can i exit the loop?

Comment: According to code in its current form, enter a value of `16`   (and read it IN the loop, not before the loop - otherwise entering (say) a value of `4` will cause the code to loop forever) .   That is the condition that causes the loop to exit (after executing the switch).    If you want to force the program to exit, simply assign `op = 16` somewhere inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your original code

```
   cin >> op;
   do {
     switch (op)
```

so you read from cin outside the loop and never read again, reordering so you read at every loop pass will ask you again the desired operation

```
   do {
     cin >> op;
     switch (op)
```

Additionally note that break does not break the loop it just breaks from the switch. Without the break the instructions from the next case will be executed as well in the switch.

If you want to break from the loop under some conditions you need to add a break outside of the switch statement, you can use a variable to "remember" if you should leave the loop.

However since you have an exit condition in your typed instructions why not make the loop exit

```
} while (op != 15);
```

which seems to make sense because of the

```
cout << "15. Exit" << endl;
```

line.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: if you did and it worked as expected do you mind accepting the answer, or if not what's wrong?

Comment: i don't know how to do it, i'm new here

Comment: to accept an answer click the checkbox below up/down buttons near the score of the question (right before it)